# what are the best practices to Declare global static or non static in App.xaml

Tags: winrt-xaml

Problem : The page loading is slow.  it takes about 10 sec for 300 customers records and databind to a ListView.

I want to increase the loading speed. So I create a global variable in App.Xaml. This allows the page that needs the data can reference it without doing a loading.

Example:

P1 -> P2 -> P3

at P2, there is less work.

I do the loading in P2. and I databind it in P3.

I dont know what I need to use.  Static or non-static Global variable.

Thanks.

```
 1) public ObservableCollection AppCustomers {get;set;}

 2) public static ObservableCollection AppCustomers {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's only a single App instance, so it shouldn't matter with which you go. Static will probably make it easier to access. Having these properties be in App.xaml is a different problem. You should probably put these in another class. Maybe in `AppCustomers` itself or some other data access class.